# ruby: group an array of dates into a hash based on which week they are with key as the first date in each week

Tags: ruby, date, group-by

For example, I have

```
['2013-12-29', '2013-12-31', '2014-01-04', '2014-01-11', '2014-01-15']
```

I expect the output as

```
{'2013-12-29'=>['2013-12-29', '2013-12-31', '2014-01-04'], '2014-01-05' => ['2014-01-11'], '2014-01-12' => ['2014-01-15']}
```

I tried %U, but it doesn't meet my requirement since it will consider the last week of last year is a different week from the first week of this year.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Using [`Enumerable#group_by`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.0/Enumerable.html#method-i-group_by):

```
require 'date'
a = ['2013-12-29', '2013-12-31', '2014-01-04', '2014-01-11', '2014-01-15']
a.group_by { |x|
  day = Date.strptime(x, '%Y-%m-%d')
  (day - day.wday).strftime('%Y-%m-%d')
}
# => {"2013-12-29"=>["2013-12-29", "2013-12-31", "2014-01-04"],
#     "2014-01-05"=>["2014-01-11"],
#     "2014-01-12"=>["2014-01-15"]}
```